# How to opt out of static site generation in next.js 13 with AppRouter

Tags: next.js13, app-router

Using next.js 13 with the new App Router, is it possible to completely opt out of static site generation for specific pages? The official documentation mentions that a page can be dynamically or statically generated, but I don't see any way to select this behaviour.

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/static-and-dynamic

Answer (score 5):

You could maybe try adding the following line to your Static Site Generated (SSG) rendered Next.js page component to potentially disable SSG on a page, for the page to then become Server-Side Rendered (SSR)?

```js
export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";
```

Documentation source: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config

Comment: This is %100 the right answer. Its a bit strange but for me for one of my nested functions that was using app headers, Next couldn't figure that out, it would call the method during build which obviously failed and i'd get this: Error: Dynamic server usage: Page couldn't be rendered statically because it used `headers`. See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/dynamic-server-error

Answer (score 1):

In the very Next.js documentation you mentioned in your question, there is a section [`Dynamic Function`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/static-and-dynamic#dynamic-functions), and here I quote:

> Dynamic functions relies on information that can only be known at request time such as a user's cookies, current requests headers, or the URL's search params.

And any page that uses those dynamic functions will be opted out of static generation by Next.js.